# Tesseract Example for Iphone

Tags: iphone, tesseract

I have compiled tesseract for using it in xcode following: http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr

I obtain the .a file, import it as framework in the iphone project, and update the header search path for tesseract header files.

So now I need a simple example in order to get start.
I can't find anything in http :// code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ or by googling.

Anyone can help me give me a starting point (a code snippet)..?!
Many ThankS!

--
Later i found this code:

`#include "baseapi.h"`

---

`TessBaseAPI::InitWithLanguage(NULL, NULL, language, NULL, false, 0, NULL);
char* text = TessBaseAPI::TesseractRect(imagedata, bytes_per_pixel,
                                          bytes_per_line, 0, 0,
                                          width, height);
TessBaseAPI::End();`

---

but when I try to compile for device (only inserting include statement without the code above) i get the following:

error:syntax error before 'PAGE_RES'
warning:type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'PAGE_RES'
warning:data definition has no type or storage class

and so on with BLOCK_LIST, IMAGE etc.

---

if compile for simulator i get

error: expected '=',',',','asm' or '**attribute**' before 'PAGE_RES'
and so on with BLOCK_LIST, IMAGE and TessBaseAPI

--- Other Update:
I found solution for include problem:
Where the include occurs must be rename the file.m in .mm extension because we have to tell xcode that we have to use objective-c and c++ together.

Comment: Hi you said that you cross compiled tesseract using that blog. I just want to know what is meant by source the configure file ?

Comment: Do you know how to manage the language file. i.e. where to keep the .traindata files? And only .traindata file enough? or do we need all the other 7/8 files?

Comment: Why not compile it into asm.js? That would have the added benefit of being able to run in theoretically *any* browser, as long as it doesn't run out of memory.

Answer (score 11):

http://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

> OCRDemo is a demo application that utilizes the Tesseract library (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) as a static library compiled under Mac OS 10.6 using the shell script found at http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/07/15/cross-compiling-for-iphone-dev-884.
>
> The program is only meant to provide a demonstration of the OCR library and it’s abilities on the iPhone, the program is not optimized in any way...

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to update `SDKROOT`, `CPPFLAGS` and `CXX`
variables. For example, here's the relevant part of my build script,
modified to work with 4.0:

```
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk
export PATH=$DEVROOT/usr/bin:$PATH
# Set up relevant environment variables
export CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/
include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -miphoneos-version-min=4.0"
export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot
$SDKROOT"
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
```

## Dynamic library location generated by the Unix package

```
 LIBPATH=$LIBFILE.dylib
    LIBNAME=`basename $LIBPATH`

export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -Wl,-
dylib_install_name,@executable_path/$LIBNAME"
```

## Static library that will be generated for ARM

```
LIBPATH_static=$LIBFILE.a
LIBNAME_static=`basename $LIBPATH_static`
# TODO: add custom flags as necessary for package
./configure CXX=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-g++-4.0.1 CC=
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld --host=arm-apple-darwin
```

Comment: I have not been able to find anywhere in apple's docs about the env. vars. , such as ; -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 .  Also the custom flag;-host=arm-apple-darwin .  Where is this stuff documented ?