# iPhone Tesseract lib error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, tesseract

I cloned the tesseract code from [here](https://github.com/MarceloEmmerich/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo/tree/master/OCRDemo) and built the iphone OCR demo for 4.3

I know there has been [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335524/tesseract-example-for-iphone) with tesseract before but I don't think my issue is the same.

The application starts ok (Simulator), and on clicking the 'show image picker' button the `UIImagePicker` appears allowing me to select an image. Selecting the image shows a 'OCRDEMO - working' Alert for 1-2 seconds, then the app crashes with debugger output of this:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol
>   in system libraries that is not
>   present on the iPhone: clock$UNIX2003
>   called from function
>   _Z17edges_and_textordPKcP10BLOCK_LIST in image OCRDemo. If you are
>   encountering this problem running a
>   simulator binary within gdb, make sure
>   you 'set start-with-shell off' first.

It doesn't help that I don't exactly know how to 'set start-with-shell off'

My fear is that this is an issue caused by 4.3 since a search for the key components of the error come up short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the same steps you did Luke and ran into the exact same issue, while running on **simulator**.

However, it works when I run on my **device** (with **Don't Code Sign**.) There's memory issues a plenty (level 1 -> level 2) but I was able to take an image using my Camera as well as from my iPhoto Library properly.

I researched everywhere for the "start-with-shell" but wasn't able to find the best way. I think that the simulator doesn't have the proper .arm libraries installed to handle this.

Hope that helps